# Php function variable passing

Tags: php, function, variables, argument-passing

How can I get function is_twitter_logged_in() to recognize variable $Twitter that's assigned in the previous function?

```
function twitter_logged_in($twitter_user) 
{
global $consumer_key; 
global $consumer_secret; 

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

if(isset($_GET['oauth_token']) || (isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token']) && isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret'])))
{
  // user has signed in
  if( !isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token']) || !isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']) )
{
    // user comes from twitter
            // send token to twitter
    $Twitter->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
           // get secret token
    $token = $Twitter->getAccessToken();
            // make the cookies for tokens
    setcookie('oauth_token', $token->oauth_token);
    setcookie('oauth_token_secret', $token->oauth_token_secret);
           // pass tokens to EpiTwitter object
    $Twitter->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);

}
else
{
 // user switched pages and came back or got here directly, stilled logged in
    // pass tokens to EpiTwitter object

 $Twitter->setToken($_COOKIE['oauth_token'],$_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']);
    }
}
elseif (isset($_GET['denied'])) {
 // user denied access
 echo 'You must sign in through twitter first';
}
else {
// user not logged in
     echo 'You are not logged in';
}
global $Twitter;

$twitter_user= $Twitter->get_accountVerify_credentials();
// show screen name (not real name)
echo $twitter_user->screen_name;
// show profile image url
//$twitter_image = $user->profile_image_url;
return $Twitter;
}

function is_twitter_logged_in($Twitter) {
global $Twitter;
$twitter_user = $Twitter;
if ( $twitter_user->screen_name == '' ){return false;}
    else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. There is no $Twitter variable in twitter_connect_mod() so what is the 'previous' function? Spend some time for us. And please, indent your code or pastebin it indented elsewhere

Comment: twitter_connect_mod() is not really relevant here, its the last two functions that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: So tailor the test case, please, so that it is smallest but still self-contained and compilable.

Answer (score 4):

`$Twitter` must first be defined outside of the function scope, then it can be referenced in functions by using `global $Twitter` and `is_twitter_logged_in()` doesn't even use `$Twitter`

Comment: True `$Twitter` isn't in `is_twitter_logged_in()`, but `$Twitter` doesn't need to be first defined outside function scope - it can be defined from inside a function with `global $Twitter`

Comment: I am doing that .. but its still returning an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Or alternatively, you can access it as $GLOBALS['Twitter'] . The variable $GLOBALS is itself a super global, and is an array with all 'globals' inside.

Comment: +1 But please avoid the usage of the global keyword unless its really necessary to use some legacy code. global is messy. It makes debug and code reading less easy.

Comment: Are you saying that defining a variable $GLOBALS['Twitter'] inside the first function will allow me to reuse the value that was assigned to that variable now in the second function?

Comment: He is saying you so, and he is right, but you should not do it this way

Comment: How should I set this up then?

Comment: Make the function that creates $Twitter return $Twitter itself, then retain the variable for subsequent use passing it to any function that needs it. As an alternative, you can use a singleton (google for "singleton pattern") or "dependency injection". I would make an example based on yours but I can't because I'm not able to read the code (no indentation). Hope it helps.

Comment: Why are you duplicating the $Twitter to $twitter_user? You're getting that error because $twitter_user is not defined as a EpiTwitter object.